# 'redirect_to root_path' does not appear as a redirect in RSpec integration test

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec2, rspec-rails

I have a rails app with the following routes

```
root :to => "pages#home"
scope "/:locale" do
  root :to => "pages#home"
  ...
  match "/sign_in" => "sessions#new"
  resources :sessions, :only => [:new, :create]
end
```

My ApplicationController contains a default_url_options() that automatically sets the locale option

My SessionsController contains the following

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
  def new
  end

  def create
    redirect_to root_path
  end
end
```

So there there is not yet any logic, just a redirect. When I run the application in a browser, go to the sign in page, submit the form (which posts to /en/sessions), then it works as expected: I am redirected to /en

The integration test however fails to recognize the redirect

```
describe "sign-in" do
  before(:each) do
    visit "/en/sign_in"
    @user = Factory.create(:user)
  end

  context "with valid attributes" do
    before(:each) do
      fill_in "email", :with => @user.email
      fill_in "password", :with => @user.password
    end

    it "should redirect to root" do
      click_button "Sign in"
      response.should be_redirect
      response.should redirect_to "/en"
    end
  end
end
```

The test fails with the message

```
5) Authentication sign-in with valid attributes should redirect to root
   Failure/Error: response.should be_redirect
     expected redirect? to return true, got false
```

So even though the application redirects correctly, RSpec does not see the response as a redirect.

If I, just for the fun of it, change the implementation of create to

```
def create
  redirect_to new_user_path
end
```

Then I get the error message

```
6) SessionsController POST 'create' with valid user should redirect to root
   Failure/Error: response.should redirect_to root_path
     Expected response to be a redirect to <http://test.host/en> but was a redirect to <http://test.host/en/users/new>
```

Which is of course the expected error message as the function is now redirecting to the wrong url. But why is it that new_user_path results in a redirect that RSpec sees as a redirect, but root_path results in a redirect that RSpec does not recognize as a redirect?

### Update

Based on comments, I modified the test to verify the status code

```
  it "should redirect to root" do
    click_button "Sign in"
    response.status.should == 302
    response.should be_redirect
    response.should redirect_to "/en"
  end
```

It leads to the error

```
5) Authentication sign-in with valid attributes should redirect to root
   Failure/Error: response.status.should == 302
     expected: 302
          got: 200 (using ==)
```

Comment: Could be a bug on rspec, did you try checking the response http code?

Comment: It may have to do with this issue https://github.com/rspec/rspec-core/pull/410.  Try using the latest version of rspec

Comment: I tried using the RSpec version from github, but it didn't help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I solved the problem. Changing the verification code to

```
it "should redirect to root" do
  current_url.should == root_url("en")
end
```

works.

I assume that the cause of my problem is because webrat actually follows the redirect, so in my original test, I was testing the response code of the second response after the redirect.

Answer (score 0):

I know this might sound dumb, but try placing the first 'root :to => "pages#home"' at the bottom of your routes file. You might also try:

```
scope "/:locale", :as => "localized" do
  root :to => "pages#home"
  ...
  match "/sign_in" => "sessions#new"
  resources :sessions, :only => [:new, :create]
end
root :to => "pages#home"
```

Then in your test you'd check for redirect to `localized_root_path`.

I may be crazy, but I think this may be a name collision with the named route. If you check `rake routes` you'll probably find that you have two named routes named root. Since routes are  'first match' you may very well just be picking up the wrong route in your test.

Comment: You are correct that I have two routes named 'root'. But the problem doesn't seem to be that I'm picking up the wrong route, because if I was, I would assume that the error would be that I'm redirecting to the wrong url. But the error is that there is no redirect at all. I've tried a bunch of different routings, none helped. This includes your suggesting, explicitly renaming the root route, and event removing the default root route. None helped :(